# Center image and Left/Right for next/previous images using predefined pages

Tags: html, css

I want to add a large < and > either on both sides of image or centered below image without changing the image location or size of image and having those lead off to the next/previous image with just an "a href"

This is what I am starting with, tried multiple suggestions on here but none of them worked.

```html
<html style="height: 100%;">
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.1">
   <title>bb2.jpg (640×480)</title>
 </head>
 <body style="margin: 0px; height: 100%; background-color: rgb(14, 14, 14);">
  <img style="display: block;-webkit-user-select: none;margin: auto;background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);transition: background-color 300ms;" src="images/bb2.jpg">
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First, an `<a>` element is for navigation, rather than performing actions, so I’d suggest using a `<button>` element instead. Secondly, you say you’ve "* tried multiple suggestions on here*" - so, which ones, what happened? What went wrong? "*…but none of them worked*" - what does that mean, specifically? Where did they fail, what didn’t work, what broke, what were you expecting to happen?

Comment: I tried about 20-30 ideas, hey left the < > under image and would not center. Tried using the simple <center> but learned it was deprecated, tried styles on the links and no luck, CSS suggestion in head still left both bottom left. Not much "broke" it but could not center with suggestions, sorry do not remember all the things I tried, they did not work, tried to play with them with no luck then just moved on to another suggestion. 
Just tried buttons with a div class=flex-parent jc-center, that just killed the page even though it was showing as working in an example with other things above.

Comment: I am simply trying to come up with a way to add the next and previous to a page that does not have it. CSS has gotten so complex,  just trying to do something that use to be EXTREEEEEMLY easy back in 2000. Now its like pulling teeth cause I have no idea what CSS could screw with others. I was trying to leave their page as is and add the links/buttons. Starting to realize why they likely did not bother.

Comment: So the arrows link to different pages, it's not a carousel? If that's the case then I misunderstood your use-case, and `<a>` elements are correct. But you do need to show your attempts, ideally as a running snippet in your question (see: "[I've been told to create a runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/82548)," over on [Meta]). As a personal request, and because it makes everybody's life easier, could you separate the inline-styles from the HTML and use a stylesheet, or `<style>` element?